# Youtube V3 Data API

Tags: c#, youtube-javascript-api, google-data-api, youtube.net-api

I would like to know a very simple way of getting the list of videos that were uploaded by user/or videos in a channel.

For example, I want to retrieve basic information about videos those were posted in the Youtube spotlight channel (http://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube/videos). All I need is read-only publicly available information.

I am so lost with the Youtube v2/v3 API / Google APIs etc. I could partially make one example work but I think all the examples are heavily biased towards "third-party" access. I started developing one example by looking at their samples and when I compiled and ran the application - it was asking me to sign-in to my google account.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what are you using? asp.net?

Comment: Was my post helpful. I would love to get some feedback as I spent time providing you a solution :)

Comment: Hi @meda - it was helpful to get started and to get an idea. however the project required the V3 API. The documentation is scattered so i thought I'll provide my solution here.

Comment: oh ok because you mention `v2` in your question, do you still need help, do you want to accept my answer or post your solution ? should I edit my answer to do it with `v3`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity you can use the api v2 like this:

```
const string channelName = "YourChannel";
var URL =string.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads",
                                                                    channelName);
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(URL))
{
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        if (reader.Name.Equals("media:player"))
        {
                string attribute = reader["url"];
                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    Response.Write("Youtube Video Link" + attribute + "<br />");
                }                            
        }
    }
}
```

You can achieve similarly using `v3` but It will require some more work